# Find the number of times each element in a vector is repeated, using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Consider a vector in MATLAB, where some elements are repeated. For example
$$v=[1 , 2, 7 , 8 ,3 ,2 ,8].$$
How can I find how many times  each element in this vector is repeated without using a loop. Is there any MATLAB command for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the unique values (here $[1, 2, 3, 7, 8]$) with

```
u = unique(v)
```

then you can count how many times each of these values appear in $v$ with

```
histc(v, u)
```

Other ways are possible.